# VB.NET WinForms - How to access objects of main thread from BackgroundWorker's thread?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm working with `BackgroundWorker`, I want the `BackgroundWorker` do the retrieval process of data from database while the user can still do another task on the form. The problem is, after retrieving the data, I can't seem to access the ListView in my `Form` from the `DoWork` event of `BackgroundWorker`, I will populate that ListView using the data I've retrieved. What should I do? Am I missing something?

Consider this example, this is how I'm doing it:

```
Public Class Test
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Label1.Text = "Hello World"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: post something you have tried...

Comment: @Binil I think the question is clear. If you know this, source code is not necessary.

Comment: @Binil I've edited my question, a simple one. Thanks for the response anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is quite clear:

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) events.

---

The sample ["How to: Download a File in the Background"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229675.aspx) shows one example way that objects can be shared between the main thread and the background worker - by arranging for such objects to be stored in variables at the class level.

Comment: Then how can I pass objects I've done from `DoWork` to any of the function, objects or `ProgressChanged` then?

Comment: @domanokz - I've added a link to another sample that shows one way to share objects between the worker and the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my first problem, now my problem is how to pass parameter to the `DoWork` since I cannot access other controls. Hm, I'll find it. Thanks again!

Comment: Ha ha! It's easy as `BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync("Hello Asynchronous World")`. I'll just extract them to `DoWork`

Answer (score 0):

`DoWorkEventArgs` contains an `Argument` property in which you can store any object, such as a user-defined class containing instructions for manipulating the UI.